# DC Adapter marked "9VDCX2", what is the X2?

Tags: dc, adapter

I have a keyboard that needs a 9v power supply. I've found one home that is marked as 9V DCX2.

What does/can the "X2" mean after DC? It literally says "9VDCX2"

Extra info:
The adapter was originally made for a home telephone.

Comment: What type of connector does it have?

Comment: Why not post a photo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a "×2" indicates that there are two outputs with the given characteristic, in this case 9VDC. A quick search finds that adapters that use a TRS phone plug frequently have this marking.

Comment: Does that mean that if I skin the cable, I'd find 2 cables, each 9V and at least 1 other cable for ground?

Comment: That is extremely likely.